# RegEx to validate and replace invalid file name characters from a custom web part file upload control

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, splistitem, file-upload, regex

**Scenario:**
I have a fileupload control in my custom webpart that attaches the uploaded files to the list item. The attachment code is given below:

```
private void UploadAttachments(Helper sharePointHelper, IList<HttpPostedFile> postedFileCollection, int itemId)
{
    // Get the list
    SPList spList = Helper.GetList(this.BackendListName);
    SPListItem itemToUpdate = null;

    // Get the existing item to update
    itemToUpdate = spList.GetItemById(itemId);

    foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in postedFileCollection)
    {
        Stream fileStream = postedFile.InputStream;
        byte[] contents = new byte[fileStream.Length];

        fileStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
        fileStream.Close();
        fileStream.Dispose();

        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);

        // Attach the file
        itemToUpdate.Attachments.Add(fileName, contents);
        itemToUpdate.SystemUpdate();
    }

}
```

When I uploaded a document with the '&' character, I got the following error logged in my SP Logs.

```
Message: The file or folder name contains characters that are not permitted.  Please use a different name.

Inner Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x81020073): The file or folder name contains characters that are not permitted.  Please use a different name.<nativehr>0x81020073</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack> 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bUnRestrictedUpdateInProgress, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback)
```

I want to change the name to valid name by replacing the invalid characters to "" and then save the file as the attachment.

I am guessing RegEx will be helpful. Thoughts??

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution... Here's how I changed my code.

```
private void UploadAttachments(Helper sharePointHelper, IList<HttpPostedFile> postedFileCollection, int itemId)
{
    // Get the list
    SPList listToUpdate = Helper.GetList(this.BackendListName);
    SPListItem itemToUpdate = null;

    // Get the existing item to update
    itemToUpdate = listToUpdate.GetItemById(itemId);

    foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in postedFileCollection)
    {
        Stream fileStream = postedFile.InputStream;
        byte[] contents = new byte[fileStream.Length];

        fileStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
        fileStream.Close();
        fileStream.Dispose();

        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);

        // Solution
        // Create the RegEx object with the pattern 
        Regex regEx = new Regex("[\~\#\%\&\*\{\}\\\:\<\>\?\/\+\|]");

        // Get the validated file name string
        string validatedFileName = regEx.Replace(fileName, "");

        // Attach the file (with the validated fileName string)
        itemToUpdate.Attachments.Add(validatedFileName, contents);
        itemToUpdate.SystemUpdate();
    }

}
```

The list of invalid characters was taken from [Nikitin's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105992/which-special-characters-are-not-allowed-in-sharepoint-2013-files-folders).

Hope this will be helpful for others InshaALLAH :)!

Answer (score 1):

@Muhammedh's solution to use `Regex` is very good. Great `Regex`, **but you can do better!**

According to this [support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/905231) from Microsoft not only are the special characters not allowed, but certain file extensions are also not allowed! And using `_vti` is not allowed either - so many restrictions!

Here's a Regex that takes all of them into account:

```
"^(\\W|_vti|_)|[^\\w]|(files|file|Dateien|fichiers|bestanden|archivos|filer|tiedostot|pliki|soubory|elemei|ficheiros|arquivos|dosyalar|datoteke|fitxers|failid|fails|bylos|fajlovi|fitxategiak)$"
```

Break it down:

```
// Matches any string that starts with a non-word character
// + any string that starts with '_vti'
// + any string that starts with an _ (underscore) (apparently this is a 'word character')
^(\\W|_vti|_)

// Matches any characters that are non-word characters
[^\\w]

// Matches all the illegal file endings listed in the support article.
(files|file|Dateien|fichiers|bestanden|archivos|filer|tiedostot|pliki|soubory|elemei|ficheiros|arquivos|dosyalar|datoteke|fitxers|failid|fails|bylos|fajlovi|fitxategiak)$
```

---

Example:

```
const string pattern = "^(\\W|_vti|_)|[^\\w]|(files|file|Dateien|fichiers|bestanden|archivos|filer|tiedostot|pliki|soubory|elemei|ficheiros|arquivos|dosyalar|datoteke|fitxers|failid|fails|bylos|fajlovi|fitxategiak)$";
const string str = "Doc with & opr.docx";
var regexedStr = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, string.Empty);
```

Yields result

> Docwithoprdocx

Comment: Thanks @daniel-ziga! I will have to use your RegEx to check during the FIleUpload itself and prompt for a new name, (Not after the List Item is added). Thanks again!!

Comment: if I use this RegEx and do a match, it should even match & character yeah? I tried with the file name 'Doc with & opr.docx' and it did not match. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Muhammedh Please see the example in my updated answer

Comment: I want to check the extensions before upload and then if the extensions are good, I want to replace the characters and then attach to the SPListItem. Sorry If was not clear enough.