# Loading Documents

Tags: file

Is it possible to stop files being loaded to Sharepoint unless they are to a set naming convention. So for example if it was a report it would be 160517Report and what ever the extension is. The problem we have is when documents are just dragged in and called anything. There also would be different naming conventions to different Webparts possibly depending on the content.
New to SharePoint so any help much appreciated.

Designer

Comment: With a development certainly. Please check this link: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151248/regex-to-validate-and-replace-invalid-file-name-characters-from-a-custom-web-par

Comment: Thank you but not a simple thing for someone new to SharePoint. It is possible then to restrict what files are called as they come into to SharePoint.

Comment: I don't think so. You can put restriction on document extension, but on document name without code, I don't think it's possible.