# Wrong URL encoding in alert email

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, alert, outlook

I discovered some strange behaviour in the "alert me" functionality of Sharepoint Online.  I've set up a alert on a file with the name "CRM process approvals: XYZ.pdf". I recieve a email when something changes in the file, but the url isn't working.
The URL I expect:

```
https://<site>.sharepoint.com/teams/marketing%20and%20sales/CRM%20process%20approvals%20XYZ.pdf
```

The url in the alert email:

```
https://<site>.sharepoint.com/teams/marketing%2520and%2520sales/CRM%2520process%2520approvals%2520XYZ.pdf
```

I tried this with multiple file names, but it seems that it is double encoding the URLs and showing '%2520' instead of '%20'. How to solve this?

Comment: Does your filename indeed include `:` (colon) in it? If it does, this will cause the URL to become encoded, and as spaces are pre-encoded to `%20`, this causes the "double-encoding" where `%20` is divided into `%25`+`20` = `%2520`.

Comment: @moe Thanks. It also happens with files without any special characters.

Comment: I'm still quite convinced that if you have files with *restricted characters* in their name, such as `:`, it affects all of the files from the same library/folder. See [what are the restricted characters](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105992/which-special-characters-are-not-allowed-in-sharepoint-2013-files-folders). If possible, could you try to reproduce the behavior on another location where are no files using restricted characters in their name?

Answer (score 0):

`%20` is encoded value for Space in '%20' we are having %, for this % symbol encoded value is %25 so here space encoded value is %2520

use `Uri.EscapeDataString()` for encoding and  `Uri.UnescapeDataString()` for decoding.