# System.IO.FileNotFoundException error when downloading file with "%" character using GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

A file with the following name exists in OneDrive browser.
[image: > sample%file name%.pdf]

When the above file is downloaded using the following request, an error is returned.

Request:

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('%2Fpersonal%2F{my endpoint}%2FDocuments%2F9355')/files('sample%25file%20name%25.pdf')/$value
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
...

cb
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code>-2147024894, System.IO.FileNotFoundException</m:code><m:message xml:lang="e
2b
n-US">File Not Found.</m:message></m:error>
0
```

Is there a SharePoint REST API limitation wherein file with "%" in its name cannot be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

```
~, #, %, & , *, {, }, \, :, <, >, ?, /, |, “
```

Above special character is not allowed for files/folder.. you need to replace these characters for create folder or files. [Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105992/which-special-characters-are-not-allowed-in-sharepoint-2013-2016-files-folders)

You have to change the file name as you are using one drive. SharePoint Library also won't allow you to upload files having above mentioned characters.

[image]

Comment: I was able to add a file with "%" character. Please refer to the screenshot in the updated question. This was added by renaming an existing file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following reference, "%" and "#" can now be used as name for folders and files.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/upcoming-changes-to-sharepoint-and-onedrive-for-business-apis-to-support-and-in-file-names/

However, there are still issues when using String-based URL APIs.
I believe that GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl is a String-based URL API.

When the following API is used, file with "%" (even "#") can be downloaded.

```
/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(DecodedUrl=@f)/$value?@f='%2Fpersonal%2F{my endpoint}%2FDocuments%2F9355%2Fsample%25file%20name%25.pdf'
```